# Pageres (phantomjs) does not return promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, phantomjs

i am using [Pageres](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres) to generate a screenshot from multiple websites.

With one source, all works fine!

Example code:

```
return new Pageres({})
   .src(url, sizes) // <- one URL
   .dest(dest)
   .run()

   .then((result) => {
      console.log("done");
      return result;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       throw error;
   });
```

But if i wanted to use more then one source and iterate through my array, it returns a Pageres Object instead of a Promise.

My Code looks like:

```
let pages = new Pageres({});

urls.forEach((url)=>{
    pages.src(url, size)
});
pages
    .dest(dest)
    .run()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("done");
        return result
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error", error);
        throw error;
    });
return pages;
```

Does someone know why the first example works and the second does not?
What can i do to return a Promise in the second example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it should be `pages = pages.src(url, size)` in the loop or you can reduce the urls to pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use reduce

```
let pages = urls.reduce(
  (page,url)=>
    page.src(url,size),
  ,new Pageres({})
);
return pages
  .dest(dest)
  .run()
  .then((result) => {
      console.log("done");
      return result
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error", error);
      throw error;
  });
```